# What happens if I have a pool_size of 1 in mongoid2 and i'm running unicorn with 3 worker_processes?

Tags: ruby, mongodb, mongoid

I'm running into a connection timeout happening.  In my scenario of pool_size 1, does it mean that the most connection that are in the pool are 1 (ie. does pool_size = max_pool_size)??

Also, what happens when I have 3 unicorn processes running? Are they all using that same connection and things are actually slower than expected?

Comment: What version of Mongoid are you using?

Comment: Mongoid2 which uses mongo-ruby-driver 1.6.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm running into a connection timeout happening. In my scenario of pool_size 1, does it mean that the most connection that are in the pool are 1 (ie. does pool_size = max_pool_size)??

In **Mongoid 2**, the pool size is the maximum number of connections that will ever be open, and are likely open at all times.

**Mongoid 3** does not use a connection pool (though it did before it switched to the Moped driver).

> Also, what happens when I have 3 unicorn processes running? Are they all using that same connection and things are actually slower than expected?

If you’re using Mongoid 3 with Rails, Mongoid will automatically reconnect when Unicorn forks a worker. If you’re using Mongoid 2 or not using Rails, you should call `Mongoid.default_session.disconnect` (in Mongoid 3, not sure what exactly to call in 2.x) in Unicorn’s [`before_fork`](http://unicorn.bogomips.org/Unicorn/Configurator.html#method-i-before_fork) hook.

Comment: Does that mean that the unicorn process gets its own separate pool of the other processes?  So pool_size: 1 should suffice?

Comment: I’ve updated my answer for Mongoid 2. Each Unicorn gets its own pool. You *must* ensure you disconnect/reconnect in `before_fork`/`after_fork` in your Unicorn config.